# Measuring misalignment between two positions on sky

Tags: coordinate, declination, astrometry, right-ascension, alignment

Let's say I have the (RA,Dec) for two positions on the sky. I want to measure the position angle between these two positions. In other words, if I had the Cartesian coordinate vectors for these two positions (say [x,y,z]) then I think the position angle PA would simply be the dot product of the two vectors, so basically cos(PA). However, RA and Dec are spherical coordinates (corresponding to $\phi$ and $\theta$ respectively), not Cartesian coordinates. How do I get cos(PA) between the two positions on the sky if I only have their (RA,Dec) instead of [x,y,z]?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_angle

> Position angle, usually abbreviated PA, is [a] convention for measuring angles on the sky in astronomy. The International Astronomical Union defines it as the angle measured relative to the north celestial pole (NCP), turning positive into the direction of the right ascension. In the standard (non-flipped) images this is a counterclockwise measure relative to the axis into the direction of positive declination.

Comment: One way would be to use your dot product! Convert each position to a unit vector using $ \mathbf{n} = cos(\phi) cos(\theta) \mathbf{\hat{x}} \ + \ sin(\phi) cos(\theta) \mathbf{\hat{y}} \ + \ sin(\theta) \mathbf{\hat{z}}$ then the cosine of the angle between the two will be their inner product. And just fyi, Smart's [Spherical Astronomy](https://archive.org/details/SphericalAstronomy) is archived!

Comment: Astronomers conventionally use $\alpha$ for right ascension and $\delta$ for declination. Also you seem to be describing [angular separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_distance); [position angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_angle) is something else.

Comment: http://www.gyes.eu/calculator/calculator_page1.htm gives the forumla !

Comment: @MikeG Sorry for the confusion, I am talking about position angle, not angular separation/distance. Position angle is the angle of a vector pointing from one (RA,Dec) to another (RA,Dec), usually measured East of North. Angular separation is much easier to calculate.

Comment: @Fattie see my previous response, sorry for the confusion. I'm talking about position angle, not angular separation.

Comment: @uhoh Thanks a lot, do you know if there is a more recent version/explanation of this? I can't find your exact formula in Chapter 2 of that book. Also, using something like astropy in Python, I can compute the Position Angle from one (RA,Dec) to another (RA,Dec) directly. After that, would cos(PA) be equivalent to the cos(angle) I get from your approach?

Comment: @quantumflash I think it's best to wait for someone to post a proper answer with the optimal equations. If you have found them in Smart, you can post an answer to your own question, that's perfectly fine in Stack Exchange. You can also search this site to see if there are other answers with the equations. The problem with spherical trig is that some forms of th equations, while correct mathematically, break down when you are using them to calculate because of zeros in the denominator, so it's best to use a recommended formulation.

Comment: @RobJeffries Unfortunately I can't edit my comment to change "convert to" to "express as", but a normal vector can certainly *point* to a coordinate on the celestial sphere.

Comment: OP, I appreciate the link to wikipedia's ideas on what astronomers apparently (joke) mean by "Position Angle".  it is totally psychotic - astronomers are nuts  :)   Not that, apart from that issue as I believe R Jeffries pointed out, you last sentence does not parse - RA-Dec is completely unrelated to XYZ.  (Unless you mean "on a unit sphere"? or some such.)

Comment: I *think* I might know what you want: between two quaternions, q' = q-1q2 is a rotation rotate you from q1 to q2  .. is that it ???

Comment: Mind you, it's possible you want the **angle of the projection of the second one, away from the projection of North (?), onto the normal plane of the first one**.  Could that be it?!  (the "eyepiece" thing in the wiki article freaks me out!)

Comment: @RobJeffries I think there is a relation between [RA,Dec] and xyz -- I think the point of RA,Dec is to *project* the xyz onto the 2D celestial sky. I guess another way to put it is: can I just do dot product of the two (RA,Dec) vectors, and would that give me a position angle (East of North)?

Comment: @Fattie yes exactly, (RA,Dec) are 2D coordinates on the celestial sky *after* you project 3D xyz onto the celestial sphere. In principle if you had something like redshift or distance, you could combine that with (RA,Dec) to get a 3D system where the redshift or distance gives you the radial component of the spherical coordinate system.

Comment: @quantumflash, however the celestial sphere is *not a fixed distance away*.

Comment: thus, "I think there is a relation between [RA,Dec] and xyz -- I think the point of RA,Dec is to project the xyz onto the 2D celestial sky"  either that makes unfortunately absolutely *no* sense, or, there is some shared convention astronomers use, to which I am not privy.

Comment: Do you mean what is the angle between the meridian and a great circle that joins points A and B? Voting to close as unclear until this is tidied up.

Comment: FWIW @RobJeffries, notice the comment by a folk under the answer - I'm thinking too it might be the angle between two great circles, for the three relevant points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you mean the angle between the meridian line through A and the great circle that goes through points A and B, then it goes something like this.

Define vectors from the origin to A and B assuming they lie on a unit sphere, such that $x_A= \cos \delta_A \cos \phi_A$, $ y_A = \cos \delta_A \sin \phi_A$ and $z_A= \sin \delta_A$, and similar for B. Here $\phi$ refers to right Ascension and $\delta$ is declination.

The great circles in question define planes that pass through the origin. A normal to the plane defined by OAB is given by the vector product $\vec{n_1}=\vec{A}\times \vec{B}$. Similarly a great circle passing through the O, A and the NCP $(0, 0, 1)$ has a normal of $\vec{n_2}= \vec{A}\times (0,0,1) = (y_A, -x_A, 0)$.

The angle you are looking for *is* the angle between these two normal vectors, which can be found from scalar product in the usual way.
$$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{n_1}\cdot \vec{n_2}}{|n_1||n_2|}=\frac{\cos \phi_{A}(y_{A}z_{B} - y_{B}z_A) + \sin \phi_{A}(x_Az_B - x_Bz_A)}{|\vec{A}\times \vec{B}|}$$

Comment: The second plane should pass through the NCP, the origin, and A.

Comment: @MikeG I think that's it.

Comment: if this doesn't get an upvote I dunno what does!  :)

Answer (score 4):

The position angle P of a body ($\alpha_1, \delta_1$) with respect to another body ($\alpha_2, \delta_2$) can be calculated from
$$tan(P)={sin(\Delta\alpha)\over cos(\delta_2)tan(\delta_1)-sin(\delta_2)cos(\Delta\alpha)}$$
where $\Delta\alpha = \alpha_1-\alpha_2$. If the denominator is negative, the position angle lies in the range of 90 to 270 degrees.

Reference: Jean Meeus, Astronomical Algorithms, Second Edition,

Comment: IDL procedure [POSANG](https://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/astro/posang.pro) uses a similar formula, citing Smart.

Comment: Could anyone be bothered to check whether my prescription yield the same formula? I suspect it does.

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be noted that position angle is not just defined by "two positions". The starting point is distinct from the ending point, resulting in a difference of $180^\circ$, depending on which one is first.

The previous answers were good, I just want to offer a different perspective/derivation. One way to define the position angle is that it's the angle from North counter-clockwise to the direction in question as measured on an [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_in_cartography) that has your starting point as the origin (assuming the astronomy standard of "North up, East left").

The algebra behind the words begins by defining the unit vector/coordinates that define the starting point:
$$\hat{n}_0 = \left[\begin{array}{c}
  \cos\alpha_0 \cos\delta_0 \\
  \sin\alpha_0 \cos\delta_0 \\
  \sin\delta_0
\end{array}\right],$$
with your ending position taking the same form with $0\rightarrow 1$. Orthographic projection on any vector is simply the process of projecting off the component of the vector in the direction of $\hat{n}_0$. The standard formula for this is
$$\vec{v}_\perp = \vec{v} - \hat{n}_0 (\vec{v}\cdot\hat{n}_0).\tag1$$

In principle, you could apply Equation (1) numerically with $\vec{v}$ as the North pole, and then as $\hat{n}_1$, then the dot product between the normalized results will give you the position angle.

Doing it that way is probably a mistake, though. See, most positions in astronomy, $\hat{n}_0$ and $\hat{n}_1$, will be separated by a small angle, so Equation (1) will suffer badly from [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_Significance). That is why it's a good idea to continue the derivation to derive a formula that doesn't have this problem.

Examining the structure of $\hat{n}_0$ is worth doing because it will simplify the algebra tremendously. It is what you get if you start with the $x$-direction unit vector, $\hat{x}$, rotate around the $y$-axis by $\delta_0$, and then rotate around the $z$-axis by $\alpha_0$. Viewed this way, finding the two vectors that are perpendicular to $\hat{n}_0$ that we need is pretty straightforward - just apply the same rotation matrices to $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$. In other words, you can read them off from the columns of the rotation matrix
\begin{align}
 R &= \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
  \cos\alpha_0 & -\sin\alpha_0 & 0 \\
  \sin\alpha_0 & \cos\alpha_0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
  \cos\delta_0 & 0 & -\sin\delta_0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  \sin\alpha_0 & 0 & \cos\alpha_0
\end{array}\right] \\
 & = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
  \cos\alpha_0 \cos\delta_0 & -\sin\alpha_0 & -\cos\alpha_0 \sin\delta_0 \\
  \sin\alpha_0 \cos\delta_0 & \cos\alpha_0 & -\sin\alpha_0 \sin\delta_0 \\
  \sin\delta_0 & 0 & \cos\delta_0
\end{array}\right].\tag2
\end{align}
I chose how to apply the signs to the sine functions in the two rotation matrices so that the first column would match $\hat{n}_0$.

Let's call the second column of (2) $\hat{E}'$, and the third column $\hat{N}'$. Notice that if we rotate a standard set of $x$-$y$ axes by 90 degrees counter-clockwise, then the $x$-axis corresponds to North and the $y$ to East. Thus, we can use the standard formula for the 2-dimensional component of a vector and its polar angle if we identify $\hat{n}_1\cdot\hat{N}'$ as the $x$-component and $\hat{n}_1\cdot\hat{E}'$ as the $y$. That formula is
\begin{align} 
 P &= \operatorname{atan2}\left(y,\,x\right)\\
   & = \operatorname{atan2}\left(\sin\delta_1\cos\delta_0 - \sin\delta_0\cos\delta_1 \cos(\alpha_1-\alpha_0),\,\cos\delta_0\sin(\alpha_1-\alpha_0)\right). \tag3
\end{align}

Because $\cos\delta > 0$ for all declinations, you could make the formula look more like the standard one from textbooks. My own instinct is to avoid using $\tan\delta$ because it diverges near the poles. This formula will work for all $\alpha$ and $\delta$, as long as the two points are distinct. The only bit that remains is to fiddle with the $x$-like argument to make it behave well, numerically, when the points are near each other. To do so, use $\sin\delta_1\cos\delta_0 = \sin(\delta_1-\delta_0) + \sin\delta_0\cos\delta_1$ and $1 - \cos(\alpha_1-\alpha_0) = 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha_1 - \alpha_0}{2}\right)$ to get
$$P  = \operatorname{atan2}\left(\sin(\delta_1-\delta_0) + 2\sin\delta_0\cos\delta_1 \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha_1-\alpha_0}{2}\right),\,\cos\delta_0\sin(\alpha_1-\alpha_0)\right). \tag4$$

In principle, you'd want to investigate when it's best to use (3) or (4) numerically. In practice, I suspect that (4) will do better than (3), in terms of numerical accuracy, in the vast majority of cases that astronomers care about.