# Position Angle Relative to North

Tags: coordinate, positional-astronomy, astrometry

I am trying to find the position angle of a star whose Ra and dec are known. I have already looked at the ['Measuring misalignment between two positions on sky'](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25306/measuring-misalignment-between-two-positions-on-sky) question and answer, but the answer gives an undefined solution if one of the points is the North Celestial Pole (NCP). I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how to find an object's position angle given its equatorial coordinates.

Comment: The position angle is the angle between three points: two objects (such as two stars in a double star) and the north celestial pole (NCP). It sounds like you only have one star, so position angle is not applicable. Are you asking for a different angle? Perhaps the parallactic angle? (Parallactic angle is the angle between NCP and the zenith.)

Comment: You've identified a degenerate case, and the formula in [JohnHoltz's answer](/a/25330) to the linked question reflects that. The direction from NCP to itself is undefined.

Comment: @JohnHoltz  Ah, thank you. The question gave information about two stars but asked 'what is the position angle of the secondary star with respect to north', which means I need to include the other star as well. Thanks again.